# Excel VBA Search for multiple file formats (PDF, DOC, DOCX, XLS)

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code to list items in folders. There are too many files that it gives #N/A after sometime running. I would like to limit files it is searching for. I don't need `.JPG` for example and `.TIFF`. How to point my search only to .PDF, .DOC, .XLS etc.?

I have tried:

```
MyFileName = Dir(Key & "*.PDF" Or "*.DOC" Or ".DOCX" Or ".XLS")
```

Here is my code:

```
For Each Key In AllFolders.keys
    'MyFileName = Dir(Key & "*.*")
    MyFileName = Dir(Key & "*.PDF") 'only PDF files
    Do While MyFileName <> ""
        AllFiles.Add (Key & MyFileName), ""
        MyFileName = Dir
    Loop
Next
```

Comment: Where do you see this error?

Comment: If I use my "tried code" it gives zero results. However there are files in folders.

Comment: I understand that, but where do you see the `#N/A` error that you mentioned?

Comment: Well.. files and folders are on company's server. I let the code run from home for a night. In one folder it listed more than 20000+ files. Today it did only 9000+ and then the rest were #N/A. Maybe server is limiting access or there is something wrong with connection. I have tried it now for two times and it lists 9000+. Then I am getting #N/A. Now I am trying to run it for each folder step by step

Comment: The code you show should not be generating an `#NA` error.  That is coming from code you are not showing, or elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To limit the file list in your collection to specific files, you can modify your `Do` loop:

```
Do While myFileName <> ""
    If myFileName Like "*.PDF" Or _
        myFileName Like "*.DOC" Or _
        myFileName Like "*.XLS" Then
        AllFiles.Add (Key & myFileName), ""
    End If
        myFileName = Dir
Loop
```

However, this seems to be an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

and your real question should be about why you are getting the `#NA` errors.

Answer (score 3):

DIR does not accept a 'mask' for multiple file extensions but it is a small matter to build your own.

```
Dim ext As String, myFileName As String

For Each key In AllFolders.keys
    myFileName = Dir(key & "*.*")
    Do While myFileName <> vbNullString
        ext = Mid(myFileName, InStrRev(myFileName, Chr(46)))
        Select Case LCase(ext)
            Case ".pdf", ".doc", ".docx", ".xls"
                Debug.Print myFileName
                AllFiles.Add (key & myFileName), vbNullString
            Case Else
                'do nothing
        End Select
        myFileName = Dir
    Loop
Next key
```